# How do I download PDF invoices from stripe.com for previous year?

Tags: python, stripe-payments, invoice

I need to download all invoices from stripe.com for the past year for accounting purposes. I didn't find a button for that, and when I contacted stripe.com support, they said it's not possible and I should use API if I can.

I found [this page](https://modernwebtools.com/stripe-invoice-exporter/), but it wasn't working. I didn't want to spend that much time on it, as I was sure this is a common use case and why fintech unicorn would not support this simple use case. Well, so I wrote a Python script for that and sharing it here. As I spend some time on it, I am sharing it here in the hope to be useful to somebody else as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the steps to create a new Stripe API Key:

- Log in to your [Stripe dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys).
- Got to the [API Keys](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys) section.
- Click on Create secret key or Create restricted key (recommended).

  - If you chose to use a restricted key, select the `Invoices` -> `Read` permission.
    Hit Save, copy the Secret key and paste it in the `STRIPE_KEY`.

```
import os
import arrow
import requests

STRIPE_KEY = "{digrin.com}"
SAVE_PATH = "./Invoices/"

import stripe


def get_invoices(year):
    last_item_id = None
    result = []
    while True:
        invoices = stripe.Invoice.list(
            api_key=STRIPE_KEY,
            status='paid',
            created={'gte': int(arrow.get(f"{year}-01-01").timestamp()), 'lte': int(arrow.get(f"{year}-12-31 23:59").timestamp())},
            limit=100,
            starting_after=last_item_id,
        )
        for invoice in invoices['data']:
            result.append({"number": invoice['number'], "url": invoice['invoice_pdf']})

        if not invoices['data']:
            break
        last_item_id = invoices['data'][-1]['id']
    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":

    invoices = get_invoices(2022)
    print(f"There are {len(invoices)} invoices.")
    for invoice in invoices:
        with open(f"{SAVE_PATH}{invoice['number']}.pdf", "wb") as f:
            f.write(requests.get(invoice['url']).content)
            print(f"Saved file {invoice['number']}.pdf")

    # check count
    file_list = os.listdir(SAVE_PATH)
    pdf_list = [file for file in file_list if file.endswith(".pdf")]
    if len(pdf_list) != len(invoices):
        print(f"WARNING: There are {len(invoices)} invoices but {len(pdf_list)} pdf files in the directory.")
    else:
        print(f"There are {len(pdf_list)} files in the directory, matches stripe response.")
```